# Facebook API error while login

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook PHP SDK with codeigniter.

When I login into facebook with app creator's id, Login functionality works fine. But when my friend login to facebook, Login functionality doesn't work.

It throws error on facebook page just saying `'An error occurred. Please try again later.'`

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with facebook app's setting. I had set it on Sandbox mode. Because of it app was accepting all the test users and creator's facebook login but not the real world id.
After turning it off everything worked fine.